# how to get drop down menu of products in adminhtml/custom-module/grid.php

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

```
//Load product model collecttion filtered by attribute set id
  $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
      ->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
  //process your product collection as per your bussiness logic
  $productsName = array();
  $products_sku = array();
  foreach($products as $p)
   {
    $productsName[$p->getId()]=$p->getName();
    $products_sku[$p->getId()]=$p->getSku();
   }
  $this->addColumn('product_N', array('header'    => Mage::helper('deals')->__('Product name'),
      'align'     =>'left',
      'index'     => 'product_N',
  'type'      => 'options',
  'option'     => $productsName,
  ));
  $this->addColumn('product_sku', array('header'    => Mage::helper('deals')->__('Product SKU'),
      'align'     =>'left',
      'index'     => 'product_sku',
  'type'      => 'options',
  'option'     => $products_sku,
  ));
```

where i am missing something cuz in drop down no values show up, where as when i `print_r()` each variable in foreach loop it is geting `array()` of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($products as $p)
{
    $productsName[$p['value']] = $p->getName();
    $products_sku[$p['value']] = $p->getSku();
}
```

perhaps?